# How to back to a full screen TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT dialog from a FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK activity?

Tags: android, window-managers

I have started a full Screen dialog with "WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT" from a Broadcast Receiver .
Then I click a button of the dialog to start an activity with a intent `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`.
Now ,the dialog is dismissed. How can I show the dialog again when I click the "back" button of the new activity?

```
doubtButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.cancel();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebLoadView.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ArrayList<String> parameters = new ArrayList<String>();
                parameters.add(url);
                parameters.add(title);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("parameters", parameters);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: You want to open dialog and activity remains in background or activity gets finished when click on back button

Comment: when click the dialog`s button ,i call the dialog`s cancel() method ,then start the activity .now i just want to back to show the dialog again when i click the activity`s "back" button.

Comment: Just override onBackPressed() method in activity and put the same code you are using at broadcast receiver to show your dialog.

Comment: oh!get it .foolish me ,thanks